# I can't convert pygame to exe

Tags: python, pygame, exe

I made an app for my friends but I can't make executable file. I tried to use pyinstaler and cx_Freeze but it didn't worked. It creates properly an exe file but It doesn't work. When I try to run executable It pops out empty cmd window and disapears without any error.

Im working on python 3.7.4.
There is code that I used to create exe with cx Freeze:

```
import cx_Freeze

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("GenshinHelper.py")]

    cx_Freeze.setup(
        name="GenshinHelper",
        options={"build_exe": {"packages":["pygame",'datetime'],
                               "include_files":['img1.jpg','img2.jpg']}},
        executables = executables
    
        )
```

Comment: have you tried your game without making it executable by directly running it with python interpreter and if yes please update us with the output of executable when run from command line

Comment: And if its not spitting out any errors, one could consider adding some logging to the entry function to see that the proper file is executed.

Comment: It spitts out Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll

Comment: I coppied mkl_intel_thread.dll file manually to folder with exe and now I can run it from Anaconda Prompt but in  windows' cmd there is still same error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way t do that;
first install pyinstaller;

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

then write this command;

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w your_file.py
```

`--onefile` will convert all the files in your project into a single file.
`-w`: command prompt (console) will not pop-up when you will run this .exe file. If your app is a console app, then remove -w.
This will convert your file into an .exe file and will run on any other computer without python installed.

More info at https://youtu.be/UZX5kH72Yx4.

Comment: Will you please explain why??

Comment: When I try to run exe It pops out error "Failed to execute script GenshinHelper" and there are many warnings during conversion.

Comment: I had issues too with this way, Windows Defender was detecting a Trojan while it was only a python file converted to exe. I send a mail to the windows defender services but they never answered.

Comment: Sorry i don't have any further info regarding this but you can check the link in my answer. That may help

Comment: Ensure that all the images,videos related to the game are in the same folder as of the `.exe`